# How to assign the configuration section to argument parameters

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Dotnetcore 2.0 project which works fine with the following arguments.

```
-s 10.0.x.x -d "TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=xxx" -f D:\code\Script\snowflaketest -t
```

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var parameters = new Parameters(args);
    return ScriptRunnerHelper.Run(parameters);
}
```

The above code works fine when we pass the arguments.

Now I have added the appsettings.json file with the argument value and updated the Main method as follows:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{       
    try   
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
        IConfigurationSection configurationSection = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("parameters");
              
        var parameters = new Parameters(configurationSection);
        return ScriptRunnerHelper.Run(parameters);
    
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
   
    return 2;
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to pass the  configurationSection to ScriptRunnerHelper.Run(parameters);

> Error:cannot convert from
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can  share `appsettings.json` code? Constructor of `Parameters` class expects a Generic List but you are passing configurationSection to it. that's why you are getting this error. You need to read the values from the configurationSection and create list of strings and pass it to Parameters constructor.

Comment: {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "parameters": "-s 10.0.xx.x -d \"TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=xxx" -f D:\code\Script\snowflaketest -t"
  }
}